# How does Square Reader (squareup) device work via earphone jack in Android?

Tags: android

https://squareup.com/reader describes a hardware card reader that plugs into earphone jack on Android (and iPhone) too.

I wonder how the Square app reads the data from the earphone jack. Is it possible to send custom data via the earphone jack, or is it just some kind of audio decoding (like how dial-up modem works)?

Comment: One thing to notice is there are 3 bands on the headphone jack... a normal stereo headphone jack has 2 bands, left and right audio.. with 3.. I think that is a serial line. I am not sure.

Comment: Check out this post about the headphone jack:

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12498/what-protocol-does-a-headphone-jack-use

Comment: @JoxTraex The 3rd band on most mobile devices is actually the microphone. It is most likely that all data transmission from the reader to the phone operates on this 3rd band simply using it as a microphone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [a teardown](http://hackaday.com/2012/04/18/reading-credit-cards-with-a-tape-head/), the Square reader is a magnetometer, similar to that found in a common cassette tape player, that connects to the ground tip and mic ring of the headphone jack. The magnetometer converts the magnetic fields in the credit card into an analog electrical signal to send the data read from the card over the microphone input to the app to [decode and interpret the analog signal](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112031856/http://andybromberg.com/credit-cards/) into usable data.

Comment: Great answer, excellent link as well for hacking the Square reader!

Answer (score 8):

Square uses regular audio signals, in the same way that a modem does.

Comment: I know that this is true on the iPhone, and I strongly suspect that it's true on Android too.  If you're really curious, plug a Square into a normal pair of speakers, swipe your card, and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

The headphones used in a iDevice (ipod, iphone, etc) are ring, ring, ring, tip.
"regular" headphones are ring, ring, tip (for stereo), the tip being ground, and the two rings being the audio (left and right).
If you add a microphone you get a third ring.

Two of the rings are outputs and one is an input.
think of the sound coming out of your headphones (that is the output) the microphone is sending sound to the iPhone so that is an input.

Square will send the device info via the mic input and receive info via one (or both of the speaker outputs).

check out this article....  http://www.creativedistraction.com/demos/sensor-data-to-iphone-through-the-headphone-jack-using-arduino/